# PrimeFaces Component for Facebook-like "Notifications" (little messages in the upper right corner)

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I'm looking for a PrimeFaces 4.0 Component to provide little messages like Facebook does in the upper right corner by clicking on the earth symbol.

Any idea?

Comment: No canned component. You have to do the work

Comment: Well, now we've got PF 5.1 but I've still no idea how to solve the problem. Tried dynamic menues & so but this isn't easy at all and maybe a little buggy too.
So still an open question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, there really seemed to be no ready-to-use component. I'n experimenting with dynamic menues which seems to offer the right functionality. But I'm currently fighting with presenting it as cute as possible ... which of course is the real challenge.

In the facelet it's nothing more than

```
          <p:menu model="#{nachrichtTeaserController.unreadMenu}"/>
```

and the controller looks soemthing like

```
  ...

  private List<Nachricht> unread;
  private MenuModel unreadMenu;

  ...

  public void initUnread() {
    unread = nachrichtFacade.findAllUnread(
            personLoginController.getCurrentUser().getMandant(),
            personLoginController.getCurrentUser());

    unreadMenu = new DefaultMenuModel();
    Integer menuItemId = 1;
    for (Nachricht nachricht : unread) {
      menuItemId++;
      DefaultMenuItem menuItem = new DefaultMenuItem(nachricht.getTeaserText());
      menuItem.setId(menuItemId.toString());
      String nachrichtIdString = nachricht.getId().toString();
      menuItem.setCommand("#{nachrichtTeaserController.show('" + nachrichtIdString + "')}");
      //menuItem.setCommand(String.format("#{nachrichtTeaserController.show('%d')}",unread.indexOf(n)));
      unreadMenu.addElement(menuItem);
    }
}

...

public String show(String nachrichtIdString) {
  Long nachrichtId = Long.valueOf(nachrichtIdString);
  Nachricht nachricht = nachrichtFacade.find(nachrichtId);
  return show(nachricht);
}
```

Two points:

- It's important to use menuItem.setId(menuItemId.toString());
  otherwise you'll get an NullPointerexception somewhere deep in
  PrimeFaces ...
- and please consider how to do "row selection" - I mean: It's easy
  to call show() but it's necessary to get some information in
  show() about which MenuItem was clicked. Unfortunately one cannot pass a reference to the nachricht so I use the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

You could adapt [Primefaces Notification Bar](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/notificationBar.jsf) for your needs, but to be honest it rather looks like a job for this famous "do-it-yourself" component to me.